# group of order $198$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

could any one tell me how many non isomorphic groups are there of order $198$? and how many elements have order $11$ in them?
A group which first come to my mind is $Z_{198}$, I really do not know, what more or how to tackle this kind of finite group classification problems.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems? There is one 11-subgroup and, hence, there are 10 elements of order 11.

Comment: I knew, but I have to revise, thank you for the comment J.H

Comment: Group whose order is two times odd have a normal subgroup of index 2, containing all odd order elements. For groups of order 198, this subgroup is abelian, since $3$ does not divide $11-1$. There are only two possibilities for this subgroup then: $C_{99}$ or $C_{33}\times C_3$.  Studying elements of order 2 in the automorphism groups of these two will yield all groups of order 198.

Comment: In particular, first consider $C_{11}\times C_9=C_{99}$. An element of order $2$ can either invert or not on $C_{11}$, and invert or not on $C_9$.  This gives four possible groups.  On $C_{11}\times (C_3\times C_3)$, an element of order $2$ can invert or not on $C_{11}$; on $C_3\times C_3$, it can fix a $0$-, $1$-, or $2$-dimensional subspace.  This gives another $2\ast 3=6$ groups, for a total of $4+6=10$ groups of order $198$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|G| =198 = 2 \times 3^2 \times 11 $ then $n_{11}=1+11k$ $| 18$ hence $n_{11} =1$ thus the sylow 11 subgroup is normal and unique and any element of order 11 will belong to the sylow 11 subgroup.Hence any group of order 198 has same number of elements of order 11. if you want to know all groups of order 198 it will require the knowledge of semidirect product. You can get non isomorphic abelian groups of order 198 like

$\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_9 \times \mathbb Z_{11} $

$\mathbb Z_6 \times  \mathbb Z_{33} $

Answer (score 1):

Up to isomorphism, there are [10](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf) groups of order 198.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|G|=198$, $G$ has a unique Sylow-$11$ subgroup since the only divisor of $198$ which is $1\pmod{11}$ is $1$.  This subgroup is normal by uniqueness.  At the same time $G$ has a Sylow-$3$ subgroup and it has order $9$.

The normal subgroup of order $11$ and the subgroup of order $9$ combine to form a subgroup $N$ of order $99$ (they must intersect to the trivial group since $11$ and $9$ are relatively prime), which is normal because it has index $2$.  There's also a subgroup $K=\left<c\right>$ of index $2$.

It is not hard to show that $N$ must be nilpotent, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{11}\times\mathbb Z_9$ or $\mathbb Z_{11}\times\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_3$, and that $G=N\rtimes_\varphi K$.  So the goal is to find all automorphisms $\alpha$ of $N$ such that $\alpha^2=1$.  For $\mathbb Z_{11}\times\mathbb Z_9$, there are four of them; for $\mathbb Z_{11}\times\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_3$, six nonisomorphic groups are yielded.